# Filter values by row and if above threshold return column title

Tags: python

This is what I have so far, but I'm stuck. I was able to filter the values that I wanted, but I can't figure out how to take those filtered values and instead of getting them in a list return column titles.

This is what my data looks like:

```
Taxa,Pop_1,Pop_2,Pop_3,Pop_4,Pop_5,Pop_6,Pop_7
IPs216:C95NTANXX:1:250590968,0.000023,0.999865,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023,0.000022
IPs159:C95NTANXX:1:250591032,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023,0.999864,0.000023
IPs286:C95NTANXX:1:250591013,0.000024,0.000024,0.000024,0.000024,0.000024,0.000024,0.999856
IPs63:C95NTANXX:1:250591090,0.000024,0.000024,0.409426,0.352769,0.000024,0.237707,0.000024
IPs892:C95NTANXX:1:250591054,0.000024,0.000024,0.999853,0.000024,0.000024,0.000024,0.000024
IPs264:C95NTANXX:1:250590956,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023,0.999864,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023
IPs716:C95NTANXX:1:250590960,0.000023,0.000023,0.999864,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023,0.000023
IPs854:C95NTANXX:1:250590951,0.000022,0.080564,0.919325,0.000022,0.000022,0.000022,0.000022
IPs914:C95NTANXX:1:250591052,0.238472,0.000023,0.000023,0.686966,0.000023,0.074471,0.000023
IPs729:C95NTANXX:1:250591019,0.000022,0.000022,0.000022,0.999869,0.000022,0.000022,0.000022
```

This is my code:

```
f=open("/home/mjohnson/Desktop/Millet_Files/final_analysis/trees/pop_info/kodo_mod_7.meanQ" , "r")
col_titles=list()
pop_values=list()
f.readline()
filtered=list()
#gives a list with column names, i need to index this to pair values with them
a=open("/home/mjohnson/Desktop/Millet_Files/final_analysis/trees/pop_info/kodo_mod_7.meanQ" , "r")
col_titles.append(a.readline())
col_names=list()
for names in col_titles:
    q=names.strip('\n').split(',')
    col_names.append(q)
#end of getting column names

for line in f:
    x=line.strip('\n').split(',')
    x=x[1:] #this has the list ignore the first values, so taxa names ignored 
    for score in x:
        if float(score) > 0.5:
            filtered.append(score+'\n')
```

Comment: Everything you do to read the file is to `readline()` i.e. one line at a time, but you don't iterate through the file.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to parse CSV files yourself? Please see the standard [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. In particular what you want is the [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class.

Ex:

```
with open('kodo_mod_7.meanQ', 'rb') as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)

    for row in reader:
        for column_label, column_value in row.iteritems():
            if not column_label.startswith('Pop_'):
                continue

            if float(column_value) > 0.5:
                yield row
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1) You don't have to throw away the first column, you can just skip over it by adjusting the loop

2) Use enumerate to number the things you are looping through when that isn't already there for you.

```
for i, score in enumerate(x[1:]):
    if float(score) > 0.5:
        filtered.append(col_names[i]+'\n')
```